# Script based DataValidation not getting all the values (Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

This code was working and although I don't recall having changed anything structure wise, it stopped working partially.
Once I select an item on cell W4, it is apparently only giving me the first option from another sheet on column C related to that item, while that the dropdown list should have about 04 items. I can't find where the flaw is:

```
function onEdit(){
  var tabLists = "ArquivoItens";
  var tabValidation = "EditarItem";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  //It checks if the active cell is where the product name is
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 23 && activeCell.getRow() == 4 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
    //if it is, it clears the Versão cell, so you can choose the ones related to the product of choice.
    activeCell.offset(0, 6).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    //specifies the data range where the Product and the related field you want filtered is on
    var makes = datass.getRange(2, 1, datass.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
    Logger.log(makes);

    //this is what I need to study - map function
    var searchArray = makes.map(function(e){return e[1];});
    var makeIndex = searchArray.indexOf(activeCell.getValue());
    Logger.log(searchArray);

    //if anything on B (where desired column data is) is found related to A, where the product sits
    if(makeIndex != -1){
    //push found items to the datavalidation list
      var validationRange = datass.getRange("C" + (2+makeIndex));
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 6).setDataValidation(validationRule);
     }
  } 
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping me build the solutions I need, while learning tons on js.

Cheers,

Comment: As it is the script gives you as data validation  the value in column C in the same row where the first instance of the value of `activeCell` is found. If you want to have four values - where are the other three supposed to come from? Is  the value of `activeCell` contained more than once in column A?

Comment: Correct, @ziganotschka! The value in Column A is repeated, with different "versions" in Column C. Then, the goal is to be able to choose which version.

Answer (score 1):

### `indexOf()` finds only the first instance of a search key

If you expect `activeCell.getValue()` to be present more than once, you either need to implement a loop where you call `indexOf()` multiple times, or - easier - use the Apps Script method [createTextFinder().findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findall).

Also, if your values of interest are not contained in an adjacent range, you cannot use `requireValueInRange()`. Use instead [requireValueInList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues).

Sample:

```
  ...
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 23 && activeCell.getRow() == 4 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
    var makes = datass.getRange(2, 1, datass.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
    var validationList = [];
    var searchArray = datass.getRange(2, 2, datass.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(activeCell.getValue()).findAll();
    for(var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++){
      var row = searchArray[i].getRow();
      var Cvalue = makes[row-1][2];
      validationList.push(Cvalue);      
    }
    if(validationList.length > 0){
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(validationList).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 6).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: TextFinder() and/or findAll() apparently require this to be added to the appsscript.json file:
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ], 

It request authorization again, but I keep getting the first option related to W4 only and when I try running the code directly from the Apps Script , it says the sheet failed to acess the document with the code and it give me the spreadsheet ID.

Comment: It's still giving this error: Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id...

Comment: TextFinder() does not require to manually add the scopes into the manifest - it will prompt you for the right scope itself after you try to run the code once manually. Depending on the rest of your code you might require other scopes. If you are not sure, it is better to remove the scopes from the manuscript and let the script obtain them by running it.

Comment: It keeps giving me error on accessing the sheet and points me to this line: var searchArray = datass.getRange(2, 2, datass.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(activeCell.getValues()).findAll();
Any ideas?

Comment: it should be `getValue()`, not `getValues()` because the latter returns you a 2D array of values from a value range, while for `TextFinder` expects a single string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

My limited knowledge doesn't allow me to play around with advanced scripting, so I looked ffor another approach and here's how I ended up getting this to work:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ArquivoItens");
  var versionList = new Array();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 23 && activeCell.getRow() == 4 && ss.getSheetName() == "EditarItem"){
    activeCell.offset(0, 6).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    var dataRng = dataSheet.getSheetValues(2, 2, dataSheet.getLastRow(), 2);

    for (var i = 0; i < dataRng.length; i++){
    if(dataRng[i].indexOf(activeCell.getValue())!=-1){
    versionList.push(dataRng[i][1])
    }
    }
    var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
    validation.setAllowInvalid(false);
    validation.requireValueInList(versionList, true);
    activeCell.offset(0, 6).setDataValidation(validation.build());

  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!